# Extend border-top of <tr> element horizontally using CSS before

Tags: html, css

I wish to extend the border-top of each `<tr>` element in a HTML table seamlessly on either side by 1rem.

```css
body {
  padding: 4rem;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

tr:before {
  content: '';                   
  display: block;
  width: 2rem;  
  border-top: 1px solid black; 
}

tr:after {
  content: '';                   
  display: block;
  width: 2rem;  
  border-top: 1px solid black; 
}
td {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Hello</td><td>Goodbye</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hello</td><td>Goodbye</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hello</td><td>Goodbye</td></tr>
</table>
```

The border appears as if it has a height of 2px rather than 1px.  How do I fix this so that the border is seamless on either side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `border-collapse: collapse`.

```css
body {
  padding: 4rem;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

tr:before {
  content: '';                   
  display: block;
  width: 2rem;  
  border-top: 1px solid black; 
}

tr:after {
  content: '';                   
  display: block;
  width: 2rem;  
  border-top: 1px solid black; 
}
td {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Hello</td><td>Goodbye</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hello</td><td>Goodbye</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hello</td><td>Goodbye</td></tr>
</table>
```